# Navbar responsivo do bootstrap não abre

Tags: bootstrap-4

Estou tentando cirar um menu responsivo mas, quando está na visualização para dispositivos pequenos, o botão aparece mas ao clicar não abre os links:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
       <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Português fácil</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Português fácil</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuPrincipal" aria-controls="menuPrincipal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


        <div id="menuPrincipal" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sobre</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Scrips -->
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal. Faça um teste com essas duas bibliotecas: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` e 
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Não deu certo, quando diminuo a tela o botão aparece, mas ao clicar os links não são mostrados

Comment: Testei aqui e funciona certinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheque se seus arquivos JS estão corretos

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Na dúvida realize os teste chamando os abaixo

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: deu certo com essa biblioteca. Valeu